# Basic python function regarding mathematics around for loop

Tags: python, string

I am making a hangman-game and attempting to create a function to
do the following;

```
calculate_points(current_score,num_of_letter,letter_type):
```

now current score = how many points you have. You get points through
guessing correct consonants,
this is +1 points per letter in string( ex: 'apples',  a^^les and
someone guessed p, that would be +2 points,
its a consonant, but vowels is the same form rather you lose a point
-1 per letter.

```
CONSONANTS = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
```

letter type can be either 'C' or 'c' for consonant, and 'V' or 'v' for
vowel. Current score starts at 0 so, current_score = 0, and user
inputs his own score starting at 0.

Then so examples:

```
calculate_points(2,3,'C') (had 2 points, guessed 3 correct letters that are consonants so + 1 point per correct guess) 2+ 3=5
5
calculate_points(3,2,'V') (had 3 points, guessed 2 correct letters that are vowels so that is (-1) points per correct guess, so 3-2 =1 
1
```

The current attempt:

```
def calculate_score(current_score,num_of_letter,letter_type):

    new_score = 0

    for i in range(0,len(CONSONTANTS)):
       if CONSONANTS[i] == letter_type:
           new_score = current_score + (num_of_letter*1)
    for i in range(0,len(VOWELS)):
       if VOWELS[i] == letter_type:
           new_score = current_score + (num_of_letter*(-1))
    return new_score
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to look into consonants and vowels given the function you want, here is a simple example:

```
>>> def calculate_score(current_score, num_of_letter, letter_type):
    sign = 1 if letter_type == 'C' else -1
    return current_score + sign * num_of_letter

>>> calculate_score(2,3,'C')
5
>>> calculate_score(3,2,'V')
1
```